# ServiceStack v4 broken gzip/deflate compression

Tags: c#, servicestack

After updating my project to ServiceStack v4, any "OptimizedResult" returned by my web service will essentially be unreadable by my web browser (tried with IE and Chrome). Instead of getting readable JSON I get garbled text. Perhaps the response header is missing an attribute (although it does specify a gzip,deflate encoding) or maybe I missed something in the release notes.

This happens with any response where I call `Request.ToOptimizedResult(response)` or `Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(...)` in my service implementation.

Comment: Could we get a little more info? I've tried the cached services locally and they render fine. Can you show the DTOs used? a basic service implementation returning mock static data would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the issue was caused by Telerik's Rad Compression in the web application. Removing the telerik lines in the web.config solved the issue.